# Fourier transform in Python with only the amplitude and frequency data

Tags: python, fft

I have a signal that I would like to perform a Fourier transform on in Python. Specifically, I have four lists describing the signal: a series of time values *t*, the amplitude of the signal at each time *A(t)*, the instant frequency at each time *f(t)*, and the phase at each time, *omega(t)*. My question is, **how can I perform a Fourier transform on this data in Python to get *A(f)*?** I know numpy and scipy have fft functions, but these take as input the raw data of the signal, which I do not have as such.

Note, *A(t)* and *f(t)* are not constant with *t*; *A(f)* would be its frequency spectrum/amplitude spectral density.

Comment: What is this *f(t)* data you have? How is it determined? The instant frequency alone does not characterize the signal, you need the phase as well. Is *f(t)* complex-valued? And does *A(t)* not describe the full signal? Or is it the envelope of the signal?

Comment: I have the instant frequency as well as the phase (should have clarified that in the OP); f(t) is real-valued. A(t) is the envelope.